# Lost formating on last page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Recently I have updated coding to [Bilingual dictionary in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58218/8380) (the minimal example published at the link) as part of [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/8380) by adding declention and conjugation tables of irregular nouns, adjectives, pronouns and verbs. With those changes of code I have lost formating of the last page formated with dictstyle, namely fancyhead and top rule and rule that splits two column page. Even with the files without tables the formating on the last page is lost.

Comment: I know it's difficult, but a MWE is necessary. Are you changing the page style somewhere?

Comment: The MWE is published on the Showcase. The nonformating started after changing the main file, not the letter files. Yes, I change the styles.

Comment: Hello! I think that if you really need help, you have to make a standard Minimal (non-)Working Example. First: It shows your own effort. Second and more important: From your text here and following the link, it seems to be close to impossible to find out what exactly you want. The title here says "Lost formatting on last page", so show a document and explain what formatting you want to achieve.

Comment: The problem is that MWE needs to be all code to track the different behaviour. That's why I have updated the answer in Showcase not to repeat all the code here. Sorry.

Comment: @chejnik You should say `\clearpage` before `\thispagestyle{empty}` (but probably it should be `\clearpage\pagestyle{empty}\printindex`; the command `\thispagestyle` doesn't issue a page changing command, so it's applied to the *current* page, which happens to be the last in the dictionary proper.

Comment: Excelent egreg. Thank you all for help. I works. I was suprised because the code had worked before but stopped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the last lines of the abridged version you put in the "Showcase" thread:

```
\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\pagestyle{dictstyle}

% the letters in alphabetical order
\input{letters/dict_letter_a.tex}
\input{letters/dict_letter_aa.tex}
% list of all letters, each letter in separate .tex file, example of letter file, see below.

% print the index of authors of photographs
\thispagestyle{empty}
\printindex
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

What's the problem? The `\thispagestyle` command applies to the *current* page, which happens to be the last one in the dictionary part. You probably want

```
\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\pagestyle{dictstyle}

% the letters in alphabetical order
\input{letters/dict_letter_a.tex}
\input{letters/dict_letter_aa.tex}
% list of all letters, each letter in separate .tex file, example of letter file, see below.

% print the index of authors of photographs
\clearpage % output the last page
\pagestyle{empty} % all pages with style "empty" from now on
\printindex
\end{document}
```